# Java - Store amount of time (not interval)

Tags: java, time

I work with an spring4 webapp that needs the logic of storing and calculating an amount of time(hours and minutes), but it isn't an interval since the amount is inserted by user or retrieved by third part app with the HH:MM format.

By now it's done with Float values which I want to change because in float the minutes are in 100 base, and not in 60 base as it's correct.
I've tried the java.time.LocalTime but it doesn't work since it's not acceptable more than 24 hrs.

I think there may be a cleaner way to deal with it.

Thanks in advance

-----EDIT

This webapp calculate overtime work. The user inputs the amount of hours the employee have worked off contractual time.

At the moment it is mapped as a float field, which is converted an calculated as below:

`float hours = //Conversion of the HH:MM string input to HH.MM float within the framework
valueToPay = hours * employee.getHourSalary();`

This way isn't right because the minutes are not being calculated correctly. I could convert the entire time to amount of minutes, but I'm searching for a cleaner way, since the java.time API offers a lot.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Please post your code and explain in more detail what the problem is - ie, give an example and share what result you get, and what you want it to be.

Comment: Alright, I will edit the question to make sure someone can make use of it if needed, I've searched a lot before asking. But these guys below got it right. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalTime` is for time of the day.

If you need a ducation, you have [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). For example, a duration of 30 hours (which would not fit in a LocalTime):

```
Duration thirtyHours = Duration.ofHours(30);
```

Comment: If you want to add a construction example, here it is : `Duration.ofHours(timeString.split(':')[0]).plusMinutes(timeString.split(':')[1]‌​)`.

Answer (score 0):

use org.joda.time.Duration

from javadoc:

An immutable duration specifying a length of time in milliseconds.

A duration is defined by a fixed number of milliseconds. There is no concept of fields, such as days or seconds, as these fields can vary in length. A duration may be converted to a Period to obtain field values. This conversion will typically cause a loss of precision however.

Duration is thread-safe and immutable.